# internal error when inserting into table with 1 column?

Tags: sql, internal, ora-00600

Basically, when I try to insert any data what so ever into a table "COURT", for example:

`INSERT INTO court VALUES('Sydney');`

i get the following error:

```
Error starting at line 1 in command:
INSERT INTO court VALUES ('Sydney')
Error at Command Line:1 Column:1
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [kqd-objerror$], [U], [0], [373],[BIN$XQQxCzAhRPCuX323VsAKNA==$0], [], [], [], [], [], [], []
00600. 00000 -  "internal error code, arguments: [%s], [%s], [%s], [%s], [%s], [%s], [%s], [%s]"
*Cause:    This is the generic internal error number for Oracle program exceptions. This indicates that a process has encountered an exceptional condition.
*Action:   Report as a bug - the first argument is the internal error number
```

Notes:

This Database is running on my university's server, but I still have full editing privileges (I've done some basic work on it before with no problem).

I am running Oracle SQL Developer to access the database. Here is a screen shot just in case:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cj8x6.jpg

Comment: It seems , they put some condition on columns, which through this exception. Ask DB administrator of your university's database about this error.

Comment: Check this example which works fine [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f789a/1)

Comment: @jWeavers cheers i'll try that now =]

Comment: @Priscy thanks! I'll be bookmarking that site! It's great to have confirmation that i'm not doing something completely wrong =D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was that I wasn't granted enough privileges as was suggested. That caused the connection to crash.

I contacted my database admin and he fixed it all up for me.

Thanks everyone!